# What primes were "pending" at the time of Wiles's proof of FLT?

Tags: number-theory, math-history

I would like to know what instances of Fermat's Last Theorem were pending at the time of Wiles's proof.

More specifically: what families of irregular primes had been discarded as possible counterexamples at the time of Wiles's proof? Was any parallel progress made between the announcement and the publication of the proof?

Comment: I believe an outline of Wiles' thinking which was narrated by Wiles himself in a Horizon documentary, where he talks about switching from the families of elliptic curves hae had been studying using prime 3 and switching to prime 5, which seemed more complicated, but solved part of the problem. This of course, was the climax of his first attempt, and didn't conclusively solve FLT.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Computational_studies

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. So, no progress was made on families of irregular primes... shocking!